# Hololens 2 - Unity Deploy Error - XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk

I am trying to deploy a basic app like only a cube with mrtk3 or mrtk2 hand interaction sample to my company hololens 2 device. I can run the app on emulator but can not on hololens 2.

I can deploy and open the app on hololens, but it renders nothing. The log file in the temp folder of the app shows the error like 'XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE';

```
XRGeneral Settings awakening...
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
UnityEngine.XR.Management.XRGeneralSettings:Awake()

[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.474][Error  ] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.477][Error  ] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.480][Error  ] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.483][Error  ] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.486][Error  ] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.490][Error  ] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.493][Error  ] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.495][Error  ] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.499][Error  ] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.502][Error  ] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.506][Error  ] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.509][Error  ] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.513][Error  ] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.516][Error  ] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.519][Error  ] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.523][Error  ] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.526][Error  ] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.529][Error  ] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.532][Error  ] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.535][Error  ] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[Subsystems] Loading plugin UnityOpenXR for subsystem OpenXR Display...
[Subsystems] OpenXR XR Plugin successfully registered Provider for OpenXR Display
[Subsystems] OpenXR XR Plugin successfully registered Provider for OpenXR Input
[Subsystems] OpenXR XR Plugin successfully registered Provider for OpenXR Display
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.548][Error  ] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.551][Error  ] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.554][Error  ] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.554][Info   ] Available Layers: (0)
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.558][Error  ] xrCreateInstance: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE
[Subsystems] Failed to initialize subsystem OpenXR Display [error: 1]
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.562][Error  ] xrPollEvent: XR_ERROR_FUNCTION_UNSUPPORTED
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.564][Info   ] 

==== Start Unity OpenXR Diagnostic Report ====


[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.564][Info   ] ==== Report Reason: System Shutdown ====


[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.564][Info   ] ==== OpenXR Init Info ====
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.565][Info   ] 
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.565][Info   ] Stage 1 Missing Entry Points: (1)
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.565][Info   ]   xrInitializeLoaderKHR
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.565][Info   ] 
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.565][Info   ] ==== OpenXR Provider Info ====
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.565][Info   ] 
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.565][Info   ] Spec Version: 1.0.29
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.565][Info   ] Provider Version: 1.9.1
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.565][Info   ] App: holode_01_21 #3159629941
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.565][Info   ] Engine: 2021.3.33f1 #36836353
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.565][Info   ] 
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.565][Info   ] ==== OpenXR Runtime Info ====
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.565][Info   ] 
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.565][Info   ] Features requested to be enabled: (3)
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.565][Info   ]   Hand Tracking: Version=1.10.0, Company="Microsoft", Extensions="XR_EXT_hand_tracking XR_EXT_hand_joints_motion_range XR_EXT_hand_tracking_data_source XR_MSFT_hand_tracking_mesh"
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.565][Info   ]   Mixed Reality Features: Version=1.10.0, Company="Microsoft", Extensions="XR_MSFT_holographic_window_attachment XR_KHR_win32_convert_performance_counter_time XR_MSFT_unbounded_reference_space XR_MSFT_spatial_anchor XR_MSFT_secondary_view_configuration XR_MSFT_first_person_observer XR_MSFT_spatial_graph_bridge XR_MSFT_perception_anchor_interop XR_MSFT_spatial_anchor_persistence XR_MSFT_scene_understanding XR_MSFT_scene_understanding_serialization XR_MSFT_scene_marker XR_MSFT_spatial_anchor_export_preview XR_MSFT_composition_layer_reprojection"
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.565][Info   ]   Motion Controller Model: Version=1.10.0, Company="Microsoft", Extensions="XR_MSFT_controller_model XR_FB_render_model"
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.565][Info   ] 
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.566][Info   ] Requested feature extensions not supported by runtime: (20)
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.566][Info   ]   XR_EXT_hand_tracking: Feature="Hand Tracking": Version=1.10.0, Company="Microsoft"
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.566][Info   ]   XR_EXT_hand_joints_motion_range: Feature="Hand Tracking": Version=1.10.0, Company="Microsoft"
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.566][Info   ]   XR_EXT_hand_tracking_data_source: Feature="Hand Tracking": Version=1.10.0, Company="Microsoft"
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.566][Info   ]   XR_MSFT_hand_tracking_mesh: Feature="Hand Tracking": Version=1.10.0, Company="Microsoft"
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.566][Info   ]   XR_MSFT_holographic_window_attachment: Feature="Mixed Reality Features": Version=1.10.0, Company="Microsoft"
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.566][Info   ]   XR_KHR_win32_convert_performance_counter_time: Feature="Mixed Reality Features": Version=1.10.0, Company="Microsoft"
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.566][Info   ]   XR_MSFT_unbounded_reference_space: Feature="Mixed Reality Features": Version=1.10.0, Company="Microsoft"
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.566][Info   ]   XR_MSFT_spatial_anchor: Feature="Mixed Reality Features": Version=1.10.0, Company="Microsoft"
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.566][Info   ]   XR_MSFT_secondary_view_configuration: Feature="Mixed Reality Features": Version=1.10.0, Company="Microsoft"
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.566][Info   ]   XR_MSFT_first_person_observer: Feature="Mixed Reality Features": Version=1.10.0, Company="Microsoft"
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.566][Info   ]   XR_MSFT_spatial_graph_bridge: Feature="Mixed Reality Features": Version=1.10.0, Company="Microsoft"
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.566][Info   ]   XR_MSFT_perception_anchor_interop: Feature="Mixed Reality Features": Version=1.10.0, Company="Microsoft"
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.566][Info   ]   XR_MSFT_spatial_anchor_persistence: Feature="Mixed Reality Features": Version=1.10.0, Company="Microsoft"
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.566][Info   ]   XR_MSFT_scene_understanding: Feature="Mixed Reality Features": Version=1.10.0, Company="Microsoft"
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.566][Info   ]   XR_MSFT_scene_understanding_serialization: Feature="Mixed Reality Features": Version=1.10.0, Company="Microsoft"
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.566][Info   ]   XR_MSFT_scene_marker: Feature="Mixed Reality Features": Version=1.10.0, Company="Microsoft"
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.567][Info   ]   XR_MSFT_spatial_anchor_export_preview: Feature="Mixed Reality Features": Version=1.10.0, Company="Microsoft"
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.567][Info   ]   XR_MSFT_composition_layer_reprojection: Feature="Mixed Reality Features": Version=1.10.0, Company="Microsoft"
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.567][Info   ]   XR_MSFT_controller_model: Feature="Motion Controller Model": Version=1.10.0, Company="Microsoft"
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.567][Info   ]   XR_FB_render_model: Feature="Motion Controller Model": Version=1.10.0, Company="Microsoft"
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.567][Info   ] 
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.567][Info   ] Available Layers: (0)
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.567][Info   ] 
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.567][Info   ] ==== Last 20 non-XR_SUCCESS returns ====
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.567][Info   ] [FAILURE] xrEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE (23x)
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.567][Info   ] [FAILURE] xrCreateInstance: XR_ERROR_RUNTIME_UNAVAILABLE (1x)
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.567][Info   ] [FAILURE] xrPollEvent: XR_ERROR_FUNCTION_UNSUPPORTED (1x)
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.567][Info   ] 
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.567][Info   ] ==== Last 20 Events ====
[XR] [3980] [14:49:52.567][Info   ] 

==== End Unity OpenXR Diagnostic Report ====
```

Do you have any idea about this problem

I tried with unity 2022 and 2021, and mrtk2 and mrtk3, deploy from unity and also vs2022, but couldn't render anything.
I checked; Initialize XR on startup, OpenXR plugin provider and hololens feature group on xr plugin management.And also Openxr settings which tutorials show.

Comment: I did some testing but couldn't reproduce your issue. Could you share with me your HoloLens OS version? For your project, which packages in MRTK are you using and what are their versions? Also, MRTK 2 provides some example scenes - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/mrtk2/running-example-scenes?view=mrtkunity-2022-05, do they work on your device?

Comment: My hololens os version is, 22621. I noticed on device portal, there is OpenXR framework package installed but 'OpenXR for Hololens' App didn't installed. I requested and waiting for deploy process. Can this caused the problem?

Comment: I also tried mrtk2 and mrtk3 examples, I get the same error message on these too.

Comment: I don't seem to find the OpenXR framework package and OpenXR for Hololens app you mentioned. Could you provide some screenshots? For HoloLens OS 22621, this is not a complete OS version, please check if your HoloLens OS is the latest version according to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-release-notes, if not, please try to update it.

Comment: Based on this information so far, I can't determine the issue. If your device cannot run all apps, it is recommended that you first check whether there are some issues with the device. For example, maybe you can try resetting the device, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-recovery.

Comment: The OpenXR app I mentioned;
https://apps.microsoft.com/detail/9P9596DJJ19R?hl=en-us&gl=US.
I can see the OpenXR framework, from device portal via usb cable.
I deployed latest os version from Advanced Recovery Companion, which is Windows Holographic, version 23H2 - November 2023 Update
Build 22621.1152. Which os version is a complete os version?

Comment: For this OpenXR for Windows Mixed Reality application, I don't think it's necessary for HoloLens. Regarding the HoloLens OS version, what I mean by incomplete is that the 22621 you provided before is not a complete version number. As for 22621.1152, it is not the latest version. Maybe you can try updating to 22621.1254.

Comment: My hololens version is, 22621.1252. I tried run the app via hololens emulator, an it succesfully ran. I accesed the device portal of emulator, and saw the 'OpenXR for Hololens' application. Therefore I am thinking maybe this application can fix the issue, because I am trying to build the app via Unity with OpenXR.